# Is it possible to save CSS changes from Elements > Styles of Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I know we can save changes from the Sources tab, so this is a different question, can we do the same thing from Elements > Styles?

( Or have the Source tab changed synchronously so that we can save it later? )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way. Copy/Paste works though.